# Can't see csv file (converted from df) in files

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, file

After saving my dataframe to a csv in a specific location, the csv file doesn't appear in the location I saved it to. Is there any reason why it possibly is not showing?

Here is the code to save my dataframe to csv:

`df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\gibso\OneDrive\Documents\JOSEPH\export_dataframe.csv', index = False)`

Even changing an empty df does not seem to work.

```
import pandas as pd

olympics={}
          

df = pd.DataFrame(olympics)
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\gibso\OneDrive\Documents\JOSEPH\export_dataframe.csv', index = False)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: are you sure the DF isn't empty ?

Comment: Yes, I was able to print the dataframe before I ran the line of code above

Comment: Even an empty dataframe will create a file. Can you post a working example script? Create an empty dataframe, do the to_csv, then try to open and read. That's a minimal test for correctness.

Comment: Ok, I created an empty df and ran the to_csv. But I still was not able to find the csv within that location. Maybe it has something to do with my computer?

Comment: here is an example scrpt: https://pastebin.com/AXQEbDYJ. Does yours do the same thing? Post what you run so we can see. I notice that you are writing to OneDrive. I assume you are checking the result on the same computer where you do the write?

Comment: Oh, and are you running on Windows? On Linux (and maybe Mac, don't know) which doesn't use drive letters, you are going to get a file in a different place. The path looks windows-like so just making sure.

Comment: Your test script should attempt to read the file after to_csv to make sure its there - the FileNotFound error is the diagnostic part that demonstrates the error in the test script itself.

Comment: @tdelaney Yes, I ran your script and it still didn't work. And yes, I am checking on the computer I  write.

Comment: ^^I am using windows

Comment: "it still didn't work" ... meaning that the open raised a FileNotFound error?

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use the module openpyxl. Example of saving:

```
import openpyxl

workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = workbook.active
# Work on your workbook. Once finished:
workbook.save(file_name) # file_name is a variable you must define
```

Don't forget installing openpyxl with pip first!